# Cartesian Closed Categories & Exponential Objects

Tags: category-theory

On pgs. 97-98 of *Categories for the Working Mathematician*, the author defines the notion of a **Cartesian Closed Category**:

[image]
[image]

**The Problem:** As far as I recall, the author never defines the notion of an exponential object $c^b$.

Now I'm aware of online definitions of an exponential object -- such as [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exponential+object) -- but in this context is it actually required to have a definition of $c^b$? Or is the author just using $c^b$ as notation for the "the image of the functor specified (whatever it may be) by the right adjunction of $- \times b$ (whose counit is similarly notationally referred to as $e : c^b \times b \rightarrow c$)?

Answer (score 2):

The condition
$$\text{hom}(a\times b,c)\cong\text{hom}(a,c^b)$$
(the isomorphism being natural) is the definition of $c^b$.
The map
$$a\mapsto\text{hom}(a\times b,c)$$
is a contravariant functor from $C$ to $\textbf{Set}$. What
Mac Lane is asserting here is that this functor is representable
(for all $b$ and $c$) and that we denote a representing object
(unique up to isomorphism) by $c^b$.